# <video> and onloadedmetadata-event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I'd like to use the dimensions of a HTML5 video element in JavaScript. The `video`-tag itself does not have any dimensions set, so I expect it to scale to the size of the video (which it does). My markup looks like this:

```
<video id="viddy" autoplay>
<source src="myvideo.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E"' />
</video>
```

When I just use jQuery to get the element's `height()` and/or `width()` I will get a default value of 300 as it will not wait for the video to load.
So what I found out on the web ([here](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/consistent-event-firing-with-html5-video/) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974157%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) is that I should be waiting for the `onloadedmetadata`-event. So I am trying to do the following in my JS:

```
var video = document.getElementById('viddy');
video.onloadedmetadata = function(e){
var dimensions = [video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight];
alert(dimensions);
}
```

Yet, the event will never fire (although the video will load and play) and I'll never get my dimensions. Same happens with a jQuery-`bind('load',` and every other way I could think of. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put your code into a `function` at the end of your HTML head (e.g. called `init`) and bind it to the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```js
function init() {
    var video = document.getElementById('viddy');
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e){
        var dimensions = [video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight];
        alert(dimensions);
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

```html
<video id="viddy" autoplay>
    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>
```

### For Chrome

You should change adding the listener to:

```
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(e){
```

```js
function init() {
    var video = document.getElementById('viddy');
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(e){
        var dimensions = [video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight];
        alert(dimensions);
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

```html
<video id="viddy" autoplay>
    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>
```

### With jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#viddy').on('loadedmetadata', function() {
        var dimensions = [this.videoWidth, this.videoHeight];
        alert(dimensions);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="viddy" autoplay>
    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>
```

Comment: Interesting. I called my JS on `$(document).ready()` and it didn't fire. Where's the difference? Thanks anyways!

Comment: Ok, so I must have made some kind of typo or whatever, it's working with `$(document).ready()` as well.... My bad.

Comment: Why does Chrome require `addEventListener()` instead of `video.onloadedmetadata`?

Comment: Apparently the loadedmetadata event sometimes fires, before the eventlistener could be added via the js  https://dev.opera.com/articles/consistent-event-firing-with-html5-video/

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Adding `loadedmetadata` listener after `DOMContentLoaded` will not guarantee the listener will be added before `loadedmetadata` event is fired, however, adding the event listener to an element created before the *video element* with `src` (e.g. `document`) and in *capture* phase or adding the event listener to the video element inline as an attribute will.

The dimensions of the video file will be loaded with the video file metadata. So you will need to wait `loadedmetadata` event to be fired then you will be able to get dimensions from `videoWidth` and `videoHeight` properties of the html video element, where they will be set and ready, these you got all correct.

**Note for `DOMContentLoaded`**: Adding the event listener after the dom content loaded event will only guarantee the exsitence of the html element in first place to be able to add an event listener on. That is the correct method of doing that thing and here it is not the issue. On the contrary, it is the cause that the issue in question has been run into: The element's existence, with a `src` attribute to load data, before the event listener added is kind of sort of the reason event listener is prone to miss the event it should catch and handle.

By the time you add this event listener to the video element, the event might have already happened, propagated and ended, since you add the event handler after the video element created with its `src` attribute. It will start loading video hence video metadata. If it is slow enough to do that your code will get a chance to be added to the video element before `loadedmetadata` event ended after video metadata has been loaded.

1. You need to register the event handler before the video
   element starts loading its video file. Here it is by with `src`
   attribute, so you need to add the handler before or same time you
   add the `src` attribute.

   You can add an inlined event attribute on the video element itself:
   `<video src="some-video-url" onloadedmetadata="somehandler">`. Here
   not sure if the handler should be defined inline too or just
   referencing work too.
2. You can add the event listener before the video element is created with a `src` attribute. That means you need to add it to another ancestor html element that is created before the video element is created wth a `src` attribute. Also that event does not *bubble* but *captures*. So, you have to add it for capture phase of the event and to a ancestor element, e.g. `document`.

```js
document.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(e){
    // if necesssary one can add custom logic here for example to check if the event target is the element we are listening the event for with event.target
    var video = e.target;
    var dimensions = [video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight];
    alert(dimensions);
}, true);
```

```html
<video id="viddy" autoplay>
    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>
```