# Video events not triggering on every refresh

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am currently trying to get the width and height of a video by using the following:

```
var vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
vid.onloadedmetadata = function () {
   var vidHeight = this.videoHeight;
   var vidWidth = this.videoWidth;
   console.log(vidHeight, vidWidth);
};
```

I noticed when I tried to use the variables later, it sometimes worked and sometimes didn't. I put a console log in (as above) and refreshed my browser. Sometimes the values show and sometimes they don't, like the onloadedmetadata is not triggering at all. Does anyone know why this is and how to get around it?

I also tried it with another event, onloadstart. This had the same behaviour.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983714/video-and-onloadedmetadata-event

Comment: I put all my JS just before the closing body tag. So it's not representative of what I want to do. Putting code in the head is not the answer.

Comment: what's your video tag look like? and which browser(s) are you seeing the issue in?

Comment: Chrome - not tested in Firefox but due to. <video preload="none" loop id="myVideo" autoplay>
                    <source src="vids/1.mov" type="video/mov">
                    <source src="vids/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="vids/1.webm" type="video/webm">
                </video>

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer (this example is in jQuery, easy enough in plain JS too though):

```
    this.options.$video.on('canplay canplaythrough', cb);

    if (this.options.$video[0].readyState > 3) {
        cb();
    }

    function cb() {
        var vidWidth = me.options.$video[0].videoWidth;
        var vidHeight = me.options.$video[0].videoHeight;
        console.log(vidWidth, vidHeight);
    }
```